# Video Player API (local / streaming HTTP - HTTPS) multi format android >= 8

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

The Android app I'm working on, has Video Playing as an important Feature.

Well... It's been 10 days since I'm struggling trying to integrate, not the best, but a good video player (streaming over HTTP and HTTPS and locally)

I tried the ***VideoView*** first, but with the lack of simple customization (adding encryption keys etc...) I moved to the ***MediaPlayer class directly with surfaceView*** : There I could add the headers with `setDataSource` method and using Java reflection to make it work with Api == 8. The problem is that MediaPlayer doesn't accept all video containers formats... and some, even in MP4 are not being played.

I then have integrated many open source projects all based on FFmpeg (pretty complicated to maintain , customize or develop additional stuff without good knowledge in C / C++) :

**[Appunite Player](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg) :** quite complete **BUT** adds at least 30 Mo to the APK size !!! + some bugs *(BTW if someone struggles to integrate it like I did, you need to know that : it needs to be built by NDK gcc 4.4.3 wich comes with NDK r8e it won't be built with gcc4.8 or gcc4.6 of the NDK10 etc..)*,

**[ijk Player](https://github.com/bbcallen/ijkplayer) :** easy to integrate, plays almost all formats, **BUT** lacks the ability to add authentication header keys which is a requirement in my case.

And now, I'm finding myself with no alternatives..

So my question is :

Is there any good Api to be :

- integrated and **embedded** in my app (not necessarily free)
- handles : **Video Playing** of a quite large amount of Formats, at least MP4, 3GPP, FLV
- if it handles Audio Playing that would be perfect (MP3, AAC)
- ability to add **HTTP/HTTPS signature keys**
- for **android API version >= 8**
- could be an HTML5 player if it respects all the previous requirement

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried VidoLAN? - http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html

Comment: Thank you. But As I said. I need something to be embedded into my app with all the requirements respected.

Comment: According to this link: https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/ you can. - "The libVLC (VLC SDK) media framework can be embedded into an application to get multimedia capabilities.
Since VLC is based on libVLC, one should be able to have the same features that VLC media player has."

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know that, I'll test it right now :)

Comment: you got it worked???

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at using the embedded version of [VLC](http://videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html) as this should cover all of your needs.

For more information please see the following link:

[Embedded VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC) - where is states:

> The libVLC (VLC SDK) media framework can be embedded into an application to get multimedia capabilities. Since VLC is based on libVLC, one should be able to have the same features that VLC media player has

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on the build right now, do you know if it accepts passing http access key headers ?

Comment: I think so I am although not 100% sure

Comment: Ok, will check and get back to you :)